# Where in the world?

Tags: geography, anagram

(This is not a part of the puzzle. I am posting this here for two reasons: first, I've already spent ~8 hours trying to solve this. Second, I find it quite interesting and want to share.)

The puzzle from https://www.janestreet.com/puzzles/current-puzzle/ says:

> The answer to this puzzle is a country you’ll find in the news.

Following with a table:

[image]

I am not looking for the final answer yet, though any particular help how to proceed after the following hint is super highly appreciated.

> Each line is a country name + 1 extra letter, S + Malawi, E + Bangladesh, A + Samoa, R + Ireland, C + El Salvador, and so on (not that hard). So the message is: Search 4 direction

Hope you like it!

(All credits to Jane Street).

Comment: As far as I know (and it worked previously) the only rule is the question plus the table itself.

Comment: (https://www.janestreet.com/puzzles/solutions/april-2018-solution/)

Answer (score 13):

> After the hint that you found it mentions the need of a direction. Logically this will be North, South, East or West (N,S,E or W). Notice how all the highlighted letters are Es.

Only view this part if you want the final answer:

> The Es refer to East so from all of them start by drawing a line East (To the right). From there you keep going until you reach another compass point and draw in the direction of the compass point and you spell letters. 
>  For example on the first ‘E’ you draw a line to the right and immediately meet a N this means you now draw a line North (Upwards). Repeat this until a letter is formed.
>
>  This gives the following image.
>  [image]
>  Meaning the answer is Togo

Comment: I don’t understand.  Please explain more clearly. Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer (continuing to use the spoiler markup) to make it clearer and more complete.